# How to send and receive in python socket at the same time?

Tags: python, sockets

I want send and receive information at the same time over a socket in Python.

You can see from the code below that I have used `threading`  but still it doesn't work. I don't know if there is a mistake or if I have misunderstood something.

Server-side code:

```py
import socket
import threading as td# 导入 socket 模块
def send():
    while True:     # 建立客户端连接
        send_text=input('send:')
        c.send(send_text.encode('utf-8'))

def recv():
    while True:
        a=s.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        print('servwe:',a)
while True:
    global t1
    global t2
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    address=('0.0.0.0',9000)              # 设置端口
    s.bind(address)        # 绑定端口
    s.listen(5)
    c,addr=s.accept()
    print('client device：',addr)# 等待客户端连接
    t1=td.Thread(target=send())
    t2=td.Thread(target=recv)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Client-

```py
import socket               # 导入 socket 模块
import threading as td
def recv():
    global data
    while True:
        a=s.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        print('server:',a)
        t1.start()
            
def send():
    while True:     # 建立客户端连接
        send_text=input('send:')
        s.send(send_text.encode('utf-8'))
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,         socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
     
    address=('192.168.68.115',9000)
    s.connect(address)      # 创建 socket 对象
    t1=td.Thread(target=send())
    t2=td.Thread(target=recv)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: You should tell in which way _it doesn't work_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sry my english is bad, i know i has typed broken english and asked unparticularly question, but i really grateful tripleee help me to re-edit,my question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it instead of posting [the same question again.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849604/problem-of-send-and-receive-in-python-socket-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1) See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Answer (score 0):

server and client:

- Don't put the `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,…` in a loop.
- You erroneously wrote `t1=td.Thread(target=send())` instead of `t1=td.Thread(target=send)` (so calling instead of passing the thread function).
- Don't ignore disconnection with

  ```
      while True:
          a=s.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
  ```

  - rather write

  ```
      while a:=s.recv(1024).decode('utf8'):
  ```

server:

- You erroneously wrote `=s.recv(1024).decode('utf8')` instead of `=c.recv(1024).decode(…)` (so trying to use the server instead of the client connection socket).

client:

- Don't try to start the threads more than once.